# dplyr: mutate new column based on multiple columns selected by variable string

Tags: r, variables, select, dplyr

Given this data:

```
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(2,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(3,2,NA,5,3,2,NA,NA,4,5),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,3,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,3,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,3,4,NA,3,3,1))
```

I want to create an extra column `min` for the rowwise minimal value of selected columns using dplyr. That's easy using the column names:

```
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(min = min(x2,x5))
```

But I have a large df with varying column names so I need to match them from some string of values `mycols`. Now other threads tell me to use select helper functions, but I must be missing something. Here's `matches`:

```
mycols <- c("x2","x5")
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = min(select(matches(mycols))))
Error: is.string(match) is not TRUE
```

And `one_of`:

```
mycols <- c("x2","x5")
 df <- df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(min = min(select(one_of(mycols))))
Error: no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
In addition: Warning message:
In one_of(c("x2", "x5")) : Unknown variables: `x2`, `x5`
```

What am I overlooking? Should `select_` work? It doesn't in the following:

```
df <- df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(min = min(select_(mycols)))
Error: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

And likewise:

```
df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = min(select_(matches(mycols))))
Error: is.string(match) is not TRUE
```

Comment: You need to use SE version of dplyr verbs when using strings. In this case use `select_()`

Comment: Doesn't work as I expected it to work either: `df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = min(select_(mycols)))` yields "Error: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: You get an error with `matches` as it takes a string (regex) as argument not a vector of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit trickier. In case of SE evaluation you'd need to pass the operation as string.

```
mycols <- '(x2,x5)'
f <- paste0('min',mycols)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(min = f)
df
# A tibble: 10 × 6
#      x1    x2    x3    x4    x5   min
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      2     3     0     1     1     1
#2      0     2     1     0     1     1
#3      0    NA     0    NA    NA    NA
#4     NA     5     1     3     1     1
#5      0     3     3     0     3     3
#6      1     2     0     0     4     2
#7      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#8     NA    NA    NA     0     3    NA
#9      0     4     0     0     3     3
#10     1     5     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I want the lowest non-NA value so I needed to adjust this code a bit. It seems changing from `min` to `pmin(na.rm=T)` works (adding na.rm=T to `min()` doesn't seem to work):

`f <- paste0('pmin(',mycols,',na.rm=T)')`
`df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(min = f)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution a bit technical with the help of `purrr` package from the tidyverse designed for functional programming.

Fist, `matches` helpers from `dplyr` takes a regex string as argument not a vector. It is a good way for you to find a regex that matches all your columns.
(in the code under you can use the `dplyr` select helper that you wish)

Then, `purrr` functions works great with `dplyr` when you understand the underlying scheme of functionnal programming.

Solution to your problem :

```r
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(2,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(3,2,NA,5,3,2,NA,NA,4,5),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,3,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,3,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,3,4,NA,3,3,1))


# regex to get only x2 and x5 column
mycols <- "x[25]"

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(min_x2_x5 =
           # select columns that you want in df
           select(., matches(mycols)) %>% 
           # use pmap on this subset to get a vector of min from each row.
           # dataframe is a list so pmap works on each element of the list that is to say each row
           purrr::pmap_dbl(min)
         )
#>    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 min_x2_x5
#> 1   2  3  0  1  1         1
#> 2   0  2  1  0  1         1
#> 3   0 NA  0 NA NA        NA
#> 4  NA  5  1  3  1         1
#> 5   0  3  3  0  3         3
#> 6   1  2  0  0  4         2
#> 7   1 NA NA NA NA        NA
#> 8  NA NA NA  0  3        NA
#> 9   0  4  0  0  3         3
#> 10  1  5  1  1  1         1
```

I won't explain further about `purrr` here but it works fine in your case